# Google Play expansion APK

Tags: android, apk, expansion

I built an app on buildbox (no code game builder)

I exported and created an aab file. I tried uploading it but said it was over 150mb. My file size as an apk is 312 mb.

I looked up this documentation for creating a expansion file but it is so foreign to me. I have no clue where to start or where to put the code snippets.

Can anyone help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

Expansion files are no longer supported with AAB. They have been replaced with *Play Asset Delivery* and *Play Feature Delivery*.

- **Play Asset Delivery**: *"It allows games larger than 150MB to replace legacy expansion files (OBBs) by publishing a single artifact to Play containing all the resources the game needs. PAD offers flexible delivery modes, auto-updates, compression, and delta patching, and is free to use. Using PAD, all asset packs are hosted and served on Google Play removing the need to use a content delivery network (CDN) to get your game resources to players."* [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery)
- **Play Feature Delivery**: *"Play Feature Delivery uses advanced capabilities of app bundles, allowing certain features of your app to be delivered conditionally or downloaded on demand. To do that, first you need to separate these features from your base app into feature modules."* [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery)

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the information., do you know of any tutorials such as YouTube videos that show how I can create this file and upload it w/ my aab?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Buildbox, I would reach out directly to that community for help on this. I [see](https://www.buildbox.com/buildbox-3-4-2-update-google-play-android-app-bundle-support-more/) that they added support for App Bundle last month, but they don't mention anything about PAD or PFD.